# Displaying the number of questions the user inputs

Tags: python, arrays, list

Currently in the process of making a True or False quiz. Would anyone be kind enough to help me out with the code? As I am unable to display the amount of questions the user wants to answer. The questions are all arranged in an array however, I am having trouble with it.

For example:

-There are 20 questions and the quiz asks the user for how many questions they want to answer

-User enters 5 questions

-Quiz displays 5 random questions out of the 20 in the list

Thank you in advance!

```css
questionlist = ["  "]

answerslist=[" "]

score = 0

questions = 0

while True :
        
questions = int(input("How many questions do you want to answer today? "))
        
if questions <= len(questionslist) : 
            
break
        
print("I only have ", len(questions_list), " in my database")

while len(questionslist) > 0 :


I need help after this please
```

Comment: Add what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break this problem into steps, then focus on the code for each separate part.

I would retrieve the user input for how many questions he/she desires and create a loop which retrieves questions from this hash map at random for the requested number of questions! In order to retrieve the questions at random you should use a random generator that will return a number between 0 and 1. You should then multiply this number by the length of the quiz and cast this number to an integer. This will then be the index to your array. You must then store the question number in another array and check to see if this question was already asked the next time a random question was picked.

In psuedo code form:

```
number_of_questions = retrieve_user_input()
questions_asked_thus_far = [] //empty array
question_number = 1
while (question_number<=number_of_questions):
   question_number = int(random_number_generator * quiz_array.length)
   if question_number is not in questions_asked_thus_ far         
       questions_asked_thus_far.append(question_number)
       question_number ++
       print question_number
```

Comment: dont forget to upvote or mark as right answer @HelpMe

Answer (score 1):

Using python 2.7:

```
import random
questions_answers = {"Question1?":"answer1","Question2?":"answer2","Question3?":"answer3","Question4?":"answer4","Question5?":"answer5"}
score = 0 
while True : 
    questions = int(raw_input("How many questions do you want to answer today? "))
    if questions == 0:
        break
    if questions > len(questions_answers) : 
        print("I only have {} in my database".format(len(questions_answers))) 
        break 
    for i in range(1, questions+1):
        rand_item = random.choice(questions_answers.keys())
        print(rand_item)
        answer = raw_input("Enter your answer:")
        if answer == questions_answers[rand_item]:
            print("Correct")
            score+=1
        else:
            print("Wrong")
    print ("Your score is {} out of {}".format(score, questions))
```

Comment: If I could upvote I would! Thank you very much for your kind help, you really dragged me out of this messy hole.